# write.csv precision R

Tags: r, csv, rounding

I am dealing with very precise numbers (maximum number of digits).

I noticed that `write.csv(x)` in R sometimes round the number.

Has anyone noticed something like that? 
What is the default number of digits saved?

Comment: This question is programming-oriented so I'm voting to migrate it to stackexachange.com as here it is off-topic.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary

Comment: and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As written in the documentation,

> In almost all cases the conversion of numeric quantities is governed
>   by the option "`scipen`" (see `options`), but with the internal equivalent
>   of `digits = 15`. For finer control, use `format` to make a character
>   matrix/data frame, and call `write.table` on that.

So the simple solution is to change the `options`, i.e.

```
options(digits = DESIRED_VALUE)
```

and the customized solution is to convert your variables to character type with `format`, e.g.

```
dat <- mtcars
dat$wt <- format(dat$wt, digits = 20)
```

and save it like this. Notice however then when using computers we are *always* dealing with rounded numbers (see Gldberg, 1991, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)), and you could find tricky outcomes do to the computer precision, e.g.

```
format(2.620, digits = 20)
## [1] "2.6200000000000001066"
```

So there is nothing "bad" with rounded values as you probably need them only to be precise up to some number of decimal places. Moreover, your measurements are also affected with measurement errors, so the precision can be illusory.

Comment: `options(digits = …)` has no effect on `write.csv`. For example, `options(digits = 3); write.csv(pi)` shows 14 decimal places.